# I need to pass three values with a dropdown

Tags: php, cakephp

On my website I have a dropdown for different units of measurement. A person can fill out his dose, then select a unit, and then submit the form. In my Units table I also have a conversion field

```
units
id | unit | conversion
1  | g    | 1000
```

I want to pass the conversion value associated with the select dropbox field, so that in my controllers, right before I save I can multiply my 'dose' with the conversion value. The problem is I don't know how to actually 'get' the conversion value. I tried running a find() to select the value that matches the units id, but it seems like my find isn't even returning any results. It looks like this

```
$this->Unit->find('first',
array(
     'conditions' => array(
         'unit' => $this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['unit_id']),
     'fields' => array('conversion')
));
```

I then do

```
$this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] = (int)$this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] * (int)$this->request->data['Unit']['conversion'];
```

---

**Found it**

```
$conv_val = $this->Unit->find('first',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'id' => $this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['unit_id']),
            'fields' => array('conversion')
            ));
        $this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] = (int)$this->request->data['RecordDrugUnit']['dose'] * (int)$conv_val['Unit']['conversion'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conversion is better done in php.

Populate your units dropdown from a db table vis:  table_id SERIAL,unit CHAR(5),conversion (FLOAT) then you can do:

```
$u=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqlidb,$_POST['unit'])
SELECT conversion from unittable WHERE unit ='$u';
```

I really don't advise that you do it this way though if this system is to be used for medical purposes.  You should use an approved database that contains the drug name, dose and form pre-connected as otherwise mistakes are certain to be made.

There are a number of suitable dbs available, or you could always create your own.

Comment: The problem is that i'm using cakephp and I don't assume I can do that fluidly. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Can't help with cake, sorry.  I just code in edit pad pro and don't use any libraries.  It must be possible.  Perhaps ask another question about how to do the mysql stuff in cake...